# How to generate Android App Bundle with C++ builder 11.2?

Tags: android, google-play, c++builder

I can not figure how to generate an Android App Bundle with C++ builder 11.2.

At this stage, I'm just checking all the steps of an android app creation, from scratch up to Google Play beta testing.

For this purpose, I wrote a very simple piece of code (one TButton with one TLabel).

I compiled the code with the following options:

- platform android 32bits
- SDK API 31 32bits
- release
- configuration development

C++ builder generates an APK which runs smoothly on my phone which is great!

My next step is to download the app on the Google Play store. I have created a Google Play store developer account for this test however I'm stuck as I can not upload the apk file as Google Play accepts Android App Bundle files only.

I have googled and found some information about generating AAB files with Delphi and the Android 64 platform here https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Submitting_Your_Android_App_to_Google_Play however I can not duplicate this with C++ builder 11.2

There is no 64bits android platform available (despite the 64bits SDK being installed) and I can not find any relevant option in the project options related to AAB files.

I have also compiled the app with the "Application Store" option but I could not find any AAB file in my project.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have found and enabled the "generate Android 32-bit and 64 bit binary (armeabi-V7a +arm64-V8a)" compiler options but no aab file is created.

Answer (score 1):

C++Builder 11.2 does not compile for 64-bit Android. See [Supported Target Platforms](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Supported_Target_Platforms).

There is an open RSP ticket about this: [RSP-24562: 64-bit Android C++](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24562)

I believe this is as a major weakness with the current RAD Studio development system, and I would suggest all users encourage Embarcadero to get the Android 64-bit C++ compiler up and running.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Do you need the 64 bit android platform to generate the AAB file or could it be done by C++ builder 11.2 and the 32 bit android platform with the right option ?

Comment: I see, 64 bits app is now a requirement of Google Play store....   The RSP-24562 ticket from 2019 just makes me realize there is no will to sort this issue.  I have to conclude that C++ builder is a dead end for writing android app. This is sad.